# Upper case from System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString()?

Tags: c#

I hope this isn't oo trivial  question, but when I call System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString() I'm getting back a lower case user ID, but other dev's are getting an upper case user ID.  How can I force ystem.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString() to return an upper case string?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString().ToUpper()
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE!!  I still have not completely answered my question, but I have a clue.  When System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString() is called from my ASP.Net app when running within IIS I get a User ID with all caps.  When I call this line from my asp.net app from within the vs.net web server my ID is in lower case.

Thanks for the response with the ToUpper() code, but I checked the production code and thatis not used.

Comment: You should develop with a local IIS to prevent further problems.

Nevertheless, for your current problem, you could use the ToUpper() or ToLower() methods of the string class.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.ToUpper()` after `.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs on to windows, he can type his name using any case: maurice, Maurice, MaUrIcE and MAURICE are all acceptable.

It is the name **as he typed it** that `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name()` returns. You can confirm this by typing your userid with unusual case and locking the workstation; the name displayed will reflect what you typed and **not** your userid as it was created.